# What is the runtime in Big O notation for the following program about prime factors?

Tags: python, big-o, prime-factoring

The following code computes the largest prime factor of a given number. This is a solution to [problem number 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) on Project Euler.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))):
        if n%i==0:
            return False 
    return True

prime_factors =[]
n=600851475143

for i in range(1,int((math.sqrt(n)))):
    if n%i==0:
        if is_prime(i):
            prime_factors.append(i)
print(max(prime_factors))
```

**My Evaluation**
The first for loop runs from 1 to sqrt(n).For every element in this loop, is_prime method runs a for loop from 1 to sqrt(i). So the runtime will be O(n^1/2 * n^1/4), i.e., O(n^3/4).
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What will your code return when n is prime?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I do think I need to refactor the code. But what about the Big-O of the available code ?

Comment: Yep, in your code, it's right. But this is not the best solution, FYI.